# Cannot use Encrpyted Home directory after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: ecryptfs

My $HOME directory is encrypted. It was ok in 13.10, but, after upgraded to 14.04 desktop by `do-release-upgrade`, I can log in, however, the home hasn't been decrypted, and cause many application crash.

If I open `nautilus` for $HOME, I can see this:

[image]

After I clicked the `Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop` and input my password, which is not changed during the upgrade, I can see my HOME directory for a while, not very long.

I found if I log in the system through SSH, I can see my all files in $HOME, which means ssh can trigger the decryption correctly. But it doesn't work if I log in through `gdm` or `lightdm`.

What I have to do now is create another user, and log in the new user first, and `ssh olduser@localhost` to trigger the decryption, and **SWITCH** back to old user, then the HOME directory works for some times.

Another strange thing is that, sometimes, even the ssh still can access decrypted files, but the GUI failed to access anything.

Is there anyone have the same problem with me? Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: That's probably a known issue https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes#Known_issues

Comment: @Braiam There is nothing talking about ecryptfs in Known Issues at this time.

Comment: @BarryKelly "Upgrade" session, [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1308530) bug.

Comment: Is this issue still reproducible?

Comment: @Briam You can read that that bug is different. That would be a failure for the user to login. In any case, I'm having a failure with ecryptfs after upgrading to 14.04, but it's caused by /dev/shm not existing. Workaround: symbolic `ln -s /run/shm /dev/shm`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the ecryptfs filesystem is installed:

```
sudo apt-get install ecryptfs-utils
```